# IO c# Проблема вывода

Tags: c#

Господа, подскажите пожалуйста, почему в этом коде вывод идет с ошибкой ?

```
static void Main()
{
    FileStream FS = new FileStream(@"D:\1.docx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    byte[] mass = new byte[FS.Length];
    for (int x = 0; x < mass.Length; x++)
    {
        if (FS.ReadByte() == -1) break;
        mass[x] = (byte)FS.ReadByte();
        FS.Flush();
    }
    FileStream FS1 = new FileStream(@"D:\2.docx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    FS1.Write(mass, 0, mass.Length);
    FS1.Flush();
}
```

Точнее создается файл, по объему полностью равен исходному, но он не работает. Если же реализовать механизм копирования без цикла, а просто встроенными средствами внесения байтов в массив и потом вывод их из массива, то все ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Все дело в смещении на один байт при каждом вызове метода ReadByte() и как следствие запись неверных данных в массив.
Решение проблемы как вариант

```
static void Main()
{
    FileStream FS = new FileStream(@"D:\1.docx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    byte[] mass = new byte[FS.Length];
    for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < mass.Length; x++)
    {
        y = FS.ReadByte();
        if (y == -1) break;
        mass[x] = (byte)y;
        FS.Flush();
    }
    FileStream FS1 = new FileStream(@"D:\2.docx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    FS1.Write(mass, 0, mass.Length);
    FS1.Flush();
}
```

Comment: В любом случае слишком жирно по памяти это все. Для docx наверное пойдёт, но для больших файлов по-другому надо.